# Python element in nested list not changing

Tags: python, list

When I print `gb0` it changes the element to "<- You are here".

When I call the `board` function it doesn't change anything.

How can I change my code to change things?

```
def board():

    gb = [['Planet Number', 'CivLevel', 'Success%', 'Fuel', 'Rocks', '']]
    for row in gb:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb0 = [['Planet 0', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb0:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb1 = [['Planet 1', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb1:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb2 = [['Planet 2', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb2:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb3 = [['Planet 3', '4', '80%', '10', '10','']]
    for row in gb3:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb4 = [['Planet 4', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb4:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb5 = [['Planet 5', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb5:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb6 = [['Planet 6', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb6:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    gb7 = [['Planet 7', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
    for row in gb7:
        print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

    print("")

    if place == 0
        gb0[0][6] = "<-- You are here"
        return gb0[0][6]

    print ("")
```

Comment: because all your variables are local to the function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Your posted code doesn't run due to a syntax error, and there's no main-level code to call your function, so it's no surprise that nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

def board():

```
place = 0


gb = [['Planet Number', 'CivLevel', 'Success%', 'Fuel', 'Rocks', '']]
for row in gb:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb0 = [['Planet 0', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
if place == 0:
    gb0[0][5] = ("<-- You are here")
for row in gb0:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb1 = [['Planet 1', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
for row in gb1:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb2 = [['Planet 2', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
for row in gb2:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb3 = [['Planet 3', '4', '80%', '10', '10','']]
for row in gb3:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb4 = [['Planet 4', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
for row in gb4:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb5 = [['Planet 5', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
for row in gb5:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb6 = [['Planet 6', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
for row in gb6:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

gb7 = [['Planet 7', '4', '80%', '10', '10', '']]
for row in gb7:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))

print("")

print ("")
```

Comment: I think your indentation is off: function **board** has a null body, which isn't syntactically legal.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow and I'm struggling to copy and paste properly.

Comment: Click on "edit" and use the "code" icon: the matched braces.

Comment: The indentation was fine when I typed it out, I just copied and pasted it wrong.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Where are you expecting a change?  There's no code outside the function you posted.  All of the variables within the function are declared, initialized, printed, and manipulated totally within the function.  None of them refers to anything outside.  Your only communication is returning the value "<-- You are here", irrespective of any data held within the board lists.

Also, note that the **gb** lists are reclaimed as soon as you exit the function.  Perhaps you need something more like this:

```
def board_init(place):

    gb = [ 
           ['Planet Number', 'CivLevel', 'Success%', 'Fuel', 'Rocks', ''],
           ['Planet 1', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' '],
           ['Planet 2', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' '],
           ['Planet 3', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' '],
           ['Planet 4', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' '],
           ['Planet 5', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' '],
           ['Planet 6', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' '],
           ['Planet 7', '4', '80%', '10', '10', ' ']
         ]

    if place > 0 and place < len(gb):
        gb[place][-1] = "<-- You are here"

    print ("")
    for row in gb:
        print("{: >15} {: >15} {: >15} {: >15} {: >15} {: >15}".format(*row))

    return gb

# Main program
game_display = board_init(3)
```

Output:

```
Planet Number        CivLevel        Success%            Fuel           Rocks                
       Planet 1               4             80%              10              10                
       Planet 2               4             80%              10              10                
       Planet 3               4             80%              10              10 <-- You are here
       Planet 4               4             80%              10              10                
       Planet 5               4             80%              10              10                
       Planet 6               4             80%              10              10                
       Planet 7               4             80%              10              10
```

Comment: I'm trying to add it on so that when you select what planet you would like to go to, it adds on the "<-- You are here" to end of the list on the main board. For example in the Planet 6 row, beside the 10 column for fuel it should say "<-- You Are Here"

Comment: How do you select the planet?  I've updated this with an attempt, using the **place** parameter for that duty.  Please edit your specification updates into the main body of the question.

Comment: Sorry, outside of the function I had a input variable (place) that asked you to select what place you wanted to go to. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like a solution.  Please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.